# 1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL' numa query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou a tentar executar esta query, e dá-me sempre o seguinte erro:

## 1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'

```
INSERT INTO ce_coins_issued (idc, idu, year, ltr, issuing, status)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 2,1,2002,NULL,NULL,'wallet') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT idc, idu, year, ltr, issuing, status FROM ce_coins_issued
WHERE idc   = 1 AND year = 2002 AND ltr = NULL LIMIT 1)
```

A tabela esta a permitir campos a NULL, visto ter dado permissão.
Pelo que me apercebi, o que faz dár este erro é ter dois NULL's no SELECT, pois caso retire um deles, a query já executa sem problemas.

Conseguem ajudar o porque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

faça assim:

```
(SELECT 2,1,2002,NULL as ltr,NULL as issuing,'wallet')
```

atribuindo um alias, não irá ocorrer duplicidade

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!! :)